# Как в Windows 10 сделать раздел системным (MBR)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, mbr

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать раздел на диске системным?
Проблема такого рода, есть диск с 2-мя разделами, из за того что в данный момент нет флешки (вернее есть, но я ее уже убил) я устанавливал windows посредством WinToHDD или WinNTSetup.
Сперва на чистый диск установил тем же WinToHDD, с помощью другого диска, а затем так получилось что на другой раздел пришлось установить другую сборку, которая теперь должна стать основной.
Так вот, на первом разделе все еще стоит загрузчик и он является активным. С помощью EasyBCD я перенес загрузчик на второй и сделал его активным, но вот беда после рестарта, зависает на "Verifiyng DMI pool Data ..........", приходится добавлять другой диск и через механизм востановления открывать консоль и через diskpart обратно делать первый раздел активным, что бы windows в итоге загрузился. В MiniTool Partition Wizard я увидел, что на нужном мне разделе (втором) стоит метка "загрузка", а на первом "активный" и "системный". Опять же, если просто сделать второй раздел "активный" и ребутнуть то будет висеть на "...DMI pool Data..." и снова придется делать первый раздел, активным. Для себя вывел, что нужно метку "системный" так же перенести. Как это сделать? Или может есть другой вариант? Напомню, что флешки нет и загрузится нужно со второго раздела, первый я хочу убрать.

Comment: Прошу меня простить... не по теме.. этот кусок текста читать тяжело уже до первой точки, пожалуйста, оформляйте вопрос красиво, шансы на ответ существенно возрастут...

Comment: @Jour Вас понял, старался более менее развернуто и понятно пояснить суть.